# Is it possible to order by latest row insert desc?

Tags: sqlite

Let me explain this a bit further.

I have a table in sqlite that looks something like this:

```
table
------
id numeric primary key,
uuid text not null,
other_field text
```

Now id is the standard auto-increment type. This table can have entries added and removed at any time so if a rowid that had been used once before was used again, that'd be fine.  I'm not using that 'table full' feature of sqlite.  There are allowed to be multiple entries with the same uuid.  The idea is I'm only interested in the last inserted entry in general.

This raises the question.  I know I can do a call like 
   "select other_field from table where uuid=? order by rowid desc"

This would be ok, but what if rowid wraps around? order by rowid desc will not give me the newest entry.

All I can think of is to add a creation_time field like

```
table
------
id numeric primary key,
uuid text not null,
other_field text
creation_time datetime
```

and then when it gets created put datetime('now') in that field.

```
select other_field from table where uuid=? order by creation_time desc
```

But this means adding an extra field and a bigger index.  Is there a built in way to do this?

Comment: How often do you add rows to this table?

Comment: Why not use an AUTOINCREMENT primary key? `rowid` is reserved in SQLite.

Comment: Actually I'm already using rowid, but it's called id.. just changed the name.  rowid and id are actually identical and you're allowed to define it, see docs.

Comment: Well put it this way, it might never wrap, but I'm making sure that if it does things don't go haywire.  This is part of a cache that gets updated quite frequently and items get removed quite frequently too.

Comment: If you are using sqlite3 your rowid is a 64-bit integer so it will take a long time to wrap. Do you have the possibility of scheduled downtime when you can create a new table with the same structure, populate it with the data, delete the old table and rename the new one to the original name? That would reinitialise your rowid to start at 1.

Comment: @d5e5. No possibility to schedule downtime.  I think I will stick with the plan I have about a create time field.  This should work for the next thousand years even if rowid wraps.

Comment: Yes, adding a creation_time field and indexing on it looks like the best option... easily understandable by whoever maintains it in the future. In 1000 years, having a slightly bigger index should not pose a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the newest ID or RowID, have a look into the command LIMIT. With the LIMIT you can return only 1 row. For your example:

```
SELECT * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

With this solution, you don't have to add another field "creation_time".

Hops this helps :)